# Javascript get number from string

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have this an example:

```
const str = "Icecream, Milk, vanilla syrup, ice cubes20.0 SR180 calories"
```

I need a way to get the **20.0** from the string, it is always positioned before **SR**

I tried to convert the string to array like so:

```
const strArr = str.split(' ');
```

and try to get the index of the object contain **SR**

```
const index = strArr.map((object) => object).indexOf('SR');
```

But it showed me a result of `-1`

I was thinking to get the element by `index - 1` to have the result of `20.0`

Any other ideas, how to make it properly?

Thanks

Comment: Regex? `str.match(/([\d\.]+) SR/)[1]`

Comment: `/(\d+(\.\d+)?) SR/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're gonna split do it on `SR`. Then extract the digits from the end of the first string.

```js
const str = "Icecream, Milk, vanilla syrup, ice cubes20.0 SR180 calories"
var arr = str.split("SR");
var rev = arr[0].trim().split("");
var num = []
while (rev.length) {
  var char = rev.pop();
  if (!(char >= '0' && char <= '9' || char == ".")) {
    break;
  }
  num.push(char);
}
var result = num.reverse().join("");
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might  help:

```
const finalNumber = str.split(' SR')[0].trim().split(' ').pop().replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
console.log(finalNumber);
```

EDITED:

```
console.log("final", str.split('SR')[0].replace(/[^\d.]/g, '').split('.').slice(-2).join('.'))
```

Comment: Will fail if there are dots before the number `"hello...12.0 SR"`

Comment: @ITgoldman Please go through updatd answer.

Comment: I'm afraid its still not perfect. There could be other numbers before the actual required number.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with following regexp:

```js
const str = "Black coffee preparing with v60 filter18.00 SR38 Calories"
const res = str.match(/\d+(.\d+)?(?= SR)/g)
console.log(res[0])
```

Regexp explain:

- `\d+` - will match any string of digits,
- `(.\d+)?` - will match floating point (optionally thanks to `?`),
- `(?= SR)` - will match a group after main expression without including it in results.

Comment: Thank you for help, your code is work for most cases but it fails using this string: "Black coffee preparing with v60 filter18.0 SR38 Calories"

Comment: @zippax Fixed. I didn't have all your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```js
const getFilter = str => str.match(/ *\d+\.\d+(?= *SR)/).map(val => val.trim());

console.log(getFilter("Black coffee preparing with v60 filter18.00 SR38 Calories")); // ["18.00"]
console.log(getFilter("Black coffee preparing with v60 filter18.0 SR38 Calories")); // ["18.0"]
console.log(getFilter("Black coffee preparing with v60 filter 18.0SR38 Calories")); // ["18.0"]
console.log(getFilter("Black coffee preparing with v60 filter18.0 SR38 Calories")); // ["18.0"]
console.log(getFilter("Black coffee preparing with v60 filter18.0SR38 Calories")); // ["18.0"]
console.log(getFilter("Black coffee preparing with v60 filter200.001 SR38 Calories")); // ["200.001"]
```

I added security on any space, which will then need .trim()

In case the value can only be a decimal with two digits before the decimal point, you will have to use this regex instead:

```
/ *\d{2}\.\d+(?= *SR)/
```

The best would be for you to send us all possible cases, for a definitive regex...

Good luck !